# Drawing a segment of a circle in Java?

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I am making a brick breaker game in Java for fun. In this game the bat is a curved arc that goes around the circumference of a circle. I am struggling to make the bat behave properly.
I am drawing an arc that comes from 2 points on the circle:

```
public void update(){

    if(dir == 1){
        angle += 0.05;
    }else if(dir == 0){
        angle -= 0.05;
    }


    x0 = a + r * Math.cos(angle);
    y0 = b + r * Math.sin(angle);
    x1 = a + r * Math.cos(angle - 0.1);
    y1 = b + r * Math.sin(angle - 0.1);

} 
public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);
    int tr = (int)Math.sqrt((x0-a)*(x0-a) + (y0-b)*(y0-b));
    int x = (int) (a - tr);
    int y = (int) (a - tr);
    int width = 2*tr;
    int height = 2*tr;
    int startAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*Math.atan2(y0-b, x0-a));
    int endAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*Math.atan2(y1-b, x1-a));
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
}
```

In theory this should work, the second points being generated from the angle going slightly further, but the length of the arc keeps varying in size...? That is where the problem lies.

[image]

Comment: Sure, so what's the first step? any pseudo-code? what library we can use ?!?!?

Comment: Start with drawing a simple brick in Java. gotta start somewher

Comment: The answer will depend on what framework you are using, for example, in Swing you could take advantage of `Arc2D`, see [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details...

Comment: Sorry, I submitted the question before I finished typing.

Comment: Extended my answer - the arc is now small and constant in size.

Answer (score 0):

This here statement breaks the pattern:

```
int y = (int) (a - tr);
```

It would make more sense to use

```
int y = (int) (b - tr);
```

And then there is the way g.drawArc is being called:

```
g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
```

The last parameter is the *angle of the arc*, so I think you want

```
g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle - startAngle );
```

possibly even

```
g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, Math.abs(endAngle - startAngle) );
```